# How to set UIDatePicker to an initial date other than "Today"

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uidatepicker

I need to set the initial date to something other than "Today" so the user is forced to make a selection.  I have found that if the user does NOT make a selection, the date/time is set to "nil";  I can send an UIAlertView, but that is after the fact.

I have looked at SO and Google, but found nothing.  How can I do this?

UPDATE:  actually, I didn't state it, but the year is not shown, only month, day and am/pm.  Without the year, they might not see  a future date.  T

Comment: Your first look should be the `UIDatePicker Class Reference`.

Comment: Why are you making your users jump through hoops like this? If the user doesn't make a selection, and `nil` is returned, why don't you check for this condition, and provide the "today" value yourself? Or even better, find out why the picker is returning nil—that doesn't sound like a correct default return value at all.

Comment: trudyscousin: "nil" is being returned; I'm working with users who are not computer literate, and am trying to force them to make a choice.  If I set it to "today", they might not see it think they don't have to set it...

Comment: Is a date value representing today not a valid input (aside from `nil` not being one, either)?

Comment: Not unless you "move" the wheel... I really would like it to select what is under the selection bar without having to move the wheels.

Comment: I wrote two other comments, but deleted them after reading the answers you've received and the comments associated with them. I'm probably off-base here, especially since I don't know the nature of your app. But the idea of "training" your users is something I find repugnant. Your users should be manipulating the date picker because of a need *they* perceive. If the picker is set to a default value that is a valid value, but the picker returns `nil` when you later query it, then that's something you should be fixing, rather than making your users perform an action to get around the problem.

Comment: You should be setting the default value of the date picker to the value that the user is most likely to want. If that is "today", then set the picker's default to "today". It is terrible UI design to make the user pick such a value if it can easily be defaulted to that value for them. If the result of setting the default to "today" is that you get `nil` from the picker then all you need to do in your code is check for `nil` and replace this with `[NSDate date]`. Make your app easier for your user, not easier for you to code.

Comment: @rmaddy: I agree with everything that you said here except for using `[NSDate date]` if the picker returns nil.  Imagine a user opening the view close to midnight, walking away for a bit and coming back after midnight.  Now the date that the picker is displaying and the one that would be saved are different, and *that* is a terrible thing as well.  (He needs to actually set the date of the picker before displaying it in the first place, or at least store the date when the picker is displayed.)

Comment: @lnafziger this case can be handled with the "significant time change" notification.

Answer (score 9):

One question, how do you know that the user will not pick that specific date that you set it to?

I would use

```
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
```

to display today's date on the date picker.

Comment: Actually, `[NSDate date]` gets the current timestamp in the form of a double representing the number of seconds since I-forget-the-exact-date in 2001 at midnight GMT. The YYYY-MM-DD stuff you're thinking about is just the default format used by the class' `-description` method (used when printing an object to the console.)

Comment: Jonathan: I was thinking... if I set the default date to yesterday, which works... now, to train the users to change the date...   Please change your comment to an answer... :D

Comment: @cory - `[NSDate date]` does not get the date in an specific format. What you claim is simply the result of logging a date object. Your whole last sentence is incorrect. And since a `UIDatePicker` shows the current date by default, there is no need at all for the code you posted.

Answer (score 7):

By doing this

```
[datePicker setDate:yourDate];
```

in `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a date in the future, and then set also a minimum date so that the user can only choose a date in the future (if that's what you're looking for).

**Programmatically**

If you are doing all this programmatically you should use these properties:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *maximumDate;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *minimumDate;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;
```

**With Interface Builder**

If you are doing it via xib (or storyboard) file, in the attributes inspector you can set all the attributes: the date, but also the minimum and maximum date, so if you want that the user can't set today as date, but only a date in the future, use the minimum date:

[image]

**PS:** Change the format if you want to show only parts of the date.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];

NSDate *aGo = [todayDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-6*24*60*60];
```

1. It will set minimum date for date picker

   `[_datePickerView setMinimumDate:aGo];`
2. When we open datepickerview the default date position is set here

   `[_datePickerView setDate:[NSDate date]];`